# Generic SQL questions

Tags: sql

I have a table A

```
ID    Term
10    A
10    B
10    C
20    A
20    B
20    E
```

what's the best way to write a sql to

- get ID 10, if I try to find (A,B,C)
- get NOTHING if I try to find (A,B)
- get ID 20, if I try to find NOT in (C,D)

.

```
Select distinct ID from TableA where Term in (A,B,C) will return both 10 and 20

Select distinct ID from TableA where Term in (A,B) will also return both 10 and 20

Select distinct ID from TableA where Term NOT in (C,D) will also return both 10 and 20
```

Thanks!

Comment: This question probably needs the 'homework' tag.

Comment: This is set theory and takes some pretty interesting uses of SQL. What database are you using (Oracle, SQL Server)?

Comment: It would help a lot if you provide us more info. What vendor is it? It will expedite things if you also provide DML's :-)

Comment: -1 for insufficient detail about the rules of this game.

Comment: @Bill - I was thinking to use the table as an example, I like to find out the generic solution to this kind of the query, it is mixed with 'in' clause and a fixed length of result set...

Comment: @cletus - it is NOT related homework.  not a student for 10+ years..

@Sam - thanks, I tried to find a generic solution by common SQL.  I don't think it is a db specific issue

Answer (score 6):

1.

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TableA
WHERE Term IN ('A','B','C')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID)=3
LIMIT 1
```

Here 3 would be the length of the set (A,B,C in this case). 2 & 3 could probably be some variation of the above.

Comment: This doesn't work in SQL Server because you need your aggregate in the SELECT statement. Also it's TOP 1 but that's beside the point.

Comment: Works in PostgreSQL. And no, depending on the database, it's either TOP or LIMIT.

Comment: in db2 its "first 1 row only"

Comment: Don't understand this answer. It doesn't work for A,B

select id from tablea where term in ('A','B') group by id having count(id)=2 limit 1 doesn't return nothing.

Comment: Right, and that's what the OP seems to want. Since there is no ID in the table that is exclusive to A and B there should be no results for this case (see his 2nd question).

Comment: Basically all the query does is group the IDs belonging to the specified set and ensure that there are no more or no less number of IDs in that group than there are set elements. The query will fail if there are duplicate rows though, but that should be solvable by using a DISTINCT.

Comment: You could get the right answer for the second question by just adding "WHERE 1 = 2". Seems like bogus questions to me if this these kinds of responses are acceptable.

Comment: @codelogic, Is your query 'form' usable for answering the second question?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want one form of query that can be used to answer all three questions, not a different kind of query for each question.

These solutions take advantage of `COUNT()` not counting `NULL`s. When the `OUTER JOIN` does not match a row in `t2`, it results in `NULL` for all columns from `t2`.

**get ID 10, if I try to find (A,B,C)**

ID 10 has three distinct term values, and we're searching for all three.

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM TableA t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA t2 
  ON (t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.term = t2.term AND t2.term IN ('A', 'B', 'C'))
GROUP BY t1.ID
HAVING COUNT(t1.term) = COUNT(t2.term);
```

**get NOTHING if I try to find (A,B)**

Both ID 10 and ID 20 have three distinct term values, but our search is only for two.  The counts are 3 = 2 for both IDs, so neither have equal counts.

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM TableA t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA t2 
  ON (t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.term = t2.term AND t2.term IN ('A', 'B'))
GROUP BY t1.ID
HAVING COUNT(t1.term) = COUNT(t2.term);
```

**get ID 20, if I try to find NOT in (C,D)**

ID 20 has three distinct term values, and all three of them are NOT 'C' or 'D'.  So the counts are equal.

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM TableA t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA t2 
  ON (t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.term = t2.term AND t2.term NOT IN ('C', 'D'))
GROUP BY t1.ID
HAVING COUNT(t1.term) = COUNT(t2.term);
```

Comment: I want to praise you for your assumption!!

Comment: it is still more to think, for example, if in the table we have (30, 'A') and (30, 'B'), the 'case 1' will be ID 10 and 30 (which the ideal result is still 10 only)...

Comment: @loping: You need to be more specific about the rules.  My solution above satisfies the cases you listed in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Q1

```
SQLite version 3.6.10
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table A(ID smallint, term varchar(1));
sqlite> insert into A values(10, 'A');
sqlite> insert into A values(10, 'B');
sqlite> insert into A values(10, 'C');
sqlite> insert into A values(20, 'A');
sqlite> insert into A values(20, 'B');
sqlite> insert into A values(20, 'E');
sqlite> SELECT ID FROM A WHERE TERM = 'A' INTERSECT SELECT ID FROM A WHERE TERM
= 'B' INTERSECT SELECT ID FROM A WHERE TERM = 'C';
10
```

Q2

```
sqlite> SELECT ID FROM A WHERE TERM = 'A' EXCEPT SELECT ID FROM A WHERE TERM = '
B';
```

returns no results. EXCEPT can also be called MINUS in some versions of SQL

Q3

```
sqlite> SELECT ID FROM A EXCEPT SELECT ID FROM A WHERE TERM = 'C' UNION SELECT I
D FROM A WHERE TERM = 'D';
20
```

Comment: Don't understand this answer either. What does it return when you focus on A,B? 

SELECT ID 
FROM A 
WHERE TERM = 'A' 
INTERSECT 
SELECT ID 
FROM A 
WHERE TERM = 'B'; 

Does it return nothing?

Comment: sqlite> SELECT ID FROM A WHERE TERM = 'A' INTERSECT SELECT ID FROM A WHERE TERM
= 'B';
10
20

It looks at the results of each SELECT query and then returns all rows which appear in the results of *all* of the SELECT queries

Comment: UNION, EXCEPT and INTERSECT are all part of the SQL standard (see http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf.html#non-join%20query%20expression) and, to me, are the simplest way to solve this type of question

Comment: I agree with the importance of union, except and intersect! But doesn't want the OP the return nothing in the case of A,B? And what does your query return in the case of A,B?

Comment: Read the answer of Bill Karwin, he makes an important assumption.

Comment: The OP doesn't state whether they want one statement form to do everything or three different statement forms. That is indeed an assumption. The answer in my post for Q2 returns the correct answer (i.e. nothing) using EXCEPT

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE mySearch (
    search_id       INT,
    val             CHAR(1),
    is_required     INT,
    is_excluded     INT
    )  

INSERT INTO mySearch VALUES (1, 'A', 1, 0)   -- Search1 : A is required  
INSERT INTO mySearch VALUES (1, 'B', 1, 0)   -- Search1 : B is required  
INSERT INTO mySearch VALUES (1, 'C', 1, 0)   -- Search1 : C is required  

INSERT INTO mySearch VALUES (2, 'A', 1, 0)   -- Search2 : A is required  
INSERT INTO mySearch VALUES (2, 'B', 1, 0)   -- Search2 : B is required  

INSERT INTO mySearch VALUES (3, 'C', 0, 1)   -- Search3 : C is excluded
INSERT INTO mySearch VALUES (3, 'D', 0, 1)   -- Search3 : D is excluded  

SELECT
    [search].search_id,
    [data].id
FROM
    TableA            AS [data]
LEFT JOIN
    my_search         AS [search]
        ON [search].val = [data].Term
GROUP BY
    [search].search_id,
    [data].ID
HAVING
    ISNULL(SUM([search].is_included),0) = (SELECT SUM(is_included) FROM mySearch WHERE search_id = [search].search_id)
    AND MAX([search].is_excluded) IS NULL
```

Should satisfy all three seaches in one query.  Unfortunately I can't test it as I'm at the in-laws house and they don't have geek toys to test on ;)